# Does Cleave trigger an adjacent enemy's mark?

Tags: dnd-4e, mark, fighter

I am playing a level 5 great weapon fighter and had a question that hasn't come up yet, but I wanted clarification in case it did.

One of my at-will powers is Cleave. My question is if I am marked and use Cleave on someone other than the marker while the marker is adjacent to me:

1. Will this trigger the mark if it hits, and I do damage to the marker?
2. Will this trigger the mark if it misses?

I realize its often better to attack the marker, but I could see a scenario where it would be to my benefit to take the penalty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most marks are triggered by the marked creature making an attack that does not include its marker. *Cleave* damages an enemy adjacent to you if the attack hits, but you do not specifically attack that creature. In fact, the power's target is "one creature." That would definitely trigger a mark. You'd take your -2 penalty to the attack roll with *cleave* along with any other effects triggered by the mark.

Comment: @waxeagle Of course, if you attacked the marker and dealt the secondary damage to the unmarked target, you'd be fine.